Toggle Show Error Squiggles in Visual Studio
Is it possible to place a Command Button in the Tool bar for Show Error Squiggles?   I would like to quickly toggle this feature off and on.  If it's not possible to place a button can I map this command to a key-board shortcut somehow?

Thank you for your assistance.  I appreciate it.
I tried asking ChatGPT. :)  No luck.

I found a decent workaround that takes two clicks.  I placed the Options button in the Tool Bar.  What ever selection you made the last time you opened Options remains in view.  This keeps the Show error squiggles in view for an easy click.



After my search and testing, Visual Studio does not support directly mapping the "Show error squiggles" toggle function to shortcut keys or buttons. You can only turn on or off the function of showing error squiggles by manually checking or unchecking the Show error squiggles checkbox in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General.
If you really want to map the "Show error squiggles" toggle functionality directly to a shortcut key or button, I suggest you report this feature request to VS Developer Community, where there are many VS developers who may be able to help you.
It is important to note that if there are enough users submitting requests for this feature, Microsoft may process the feature request in this area, and if there are not many users submitting the feature request, Microsoft may not consider this aspect of the feature.

Thank you for your response Cody.  I found a decent work around.  Please see my answer below.
